# Como fazer uma soma de matriz utilizando memória compartilhada?

Tags: c, linux, memória

Necessito de ajudar para realizar uma soma de matrizes utilizando memória compartilhada.

```
#define LINHAS 3
#define COLUNAS 3
#define PULAR_LINHA printf("\n")

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  int linha, coluna;    //indices
  int pid, id;
  int matriz1[][COLUNAS] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };
  int matriz2[][COLUNAS] = { {3,5,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };
  int segmento, status;
  segmento = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int)*18, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
  int *matrizSolucao = (int*)shmat(segmento, NULL, 0);
  id = fork();

  if (id == 0)  // Processo filho
  {
        for(linha = 0; linha < LINHAS; linha++)
        {
            for(coluna = 0; coluna < COLUNAS; coluna++)
            printf("%d\t", *matrizSolucao);
            printf("\n");
        }
  }
  else          // Processo pai
  {
        pid = wait(&status);
        for(linha = 0; linha < LINHAS; linha++)
        {
            for(coluna = 0; coluna < COLUNAS; coluna++)
            *matrizSolucao = matriz1[linha][coluna] + matriz2[linha][coluna];
        }
  }
  //Libera a mmoria compartilhada do processo
  shmdt(matrizSolucao);
  //Libera a memoria compartilhada
  shmctl(segmento, IPC_RMID, 0);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Com esse código a matriz de fato aparece, porém com todos os seus valores zerados, alguém pode dar uma ajuda?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

No teu código, o processo filho imprime; o processo pai calcula.
O processo pai espera pelo filho terminar antes de calcular, por isso o processo filho imprime zeros.

Troca os códigos dos processos pai e filho.

Comment: Obrigado pela informação, inverti o código do processo pai e do filho, porém agora ao invés de zeros está imprimindo apenas 18, verifiquei que só está fazendo a soma das últimas posições e colocando esse resultado na matriz toda, o que pode ser?

Comment: a instrucao `*matrizSolucao = matriz1[linha][coluna] + matriz2[linha][coluna];` escreve sempre no mesmo espaco.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que vi no código você faz:

```
*matrizSolucao = matriz1[linha][coluna] + matriz2[linha][coluna]
```

Creio que vc está sempre colocando a soma na primeira posição, ou toda soma que vc fizer estará indo para a primeira posição e não indo cada uma para sua posição certa.

E quando você faz:

```
for(linha = 0; linha < LINHAS; linha++)
{
    for(coluna = 0; coluna < COLUNAS; coluna++)
        printf("%d\t", *matrizSolucao);
        printf("\n");
}
```

Você está novamente imprimindo a primeira posição todas as vezes.

E sobre os valores zerados é aquilo mesmo que o pmd disse aí em cima sobre o filho estar invertido com o pai.